# The difference between 'Replay' and 'Replay!'

Tags: word-choice

While writing content for a game, I got stuck in naming a button. Now, this button shows how the player ***played*** the game. Clicking this button will again *play* the recorded game that has just ended. This feature is to learn what all mistakes the player has made during the game.

Now, the button is little and one word is what it can occupy. I wrote **'Replay'** because we have replays in baseball, cricket, lawn tennis, and the like.

The developer said that 'replay' also means 'Playing Again.' And, she's right! We don't want our gamers to get confused.

The word is the same: 'replay,' but it means two things: playing again **and** playing the recorded game that has just ended.

What solution you can think of?

Comment: With the constraints given this isn't a real answer, but if a larger button COULD be used then "Watch Replay" would be very easily understood.

Comment: I think just having an icon of a video camera and no words might be a solution; especially if you can give it a tooltip on hoverover that tells the user what the button does

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On one hand it may seem a serious problem but on the other I came across this often in racing games like Porsche Unleashed, Most Wanted, FlatOut and etc.

There are a few solutions here.

1. Leave the word as is "**Replay**" and remember that by pressing this button a player won't be angry with having to start the game again. Notice that in most games "**Replay**" means "*watch the played game*". If it were something like "**Play again**" or "**Re-play**" it would make more sense to worry.
2. Use a different term instead of "**Replay**". In some games I remember coming across the verbs "**Flashback**" and "**Play back**", as well as "**Review**".
3. Try a very different approach by using verbs like "**Rewind**" for instance.

Comment: +1 for the other alternatives. I liked Rewind, Flashback...etc

Comment: I like the hyphen suggestion. _Re-play_ means play again, not play the recording.

Comment: I like all of this except for "Survey" I don't think I've ever come across this in a video game and would be a little confused. To me it seems like looking at the statistical data rather than watching a replay.

Comment: @LateralTerminal If I saw a "Survey" button after playing a game I'd expect it to give me a feedback form to fill out, surveying how I felt about the game experience or something.

Comment: @amalloy yeah that too.

Answer (score 12):

In most games, the "replay" means to play the game over, so using this to show an "instant replay" of the previous action would be confusing.

I suggest instead using **review** (as in re-"view", to view again), since you can't fit "instant replay" onto the small button. While players might not initially know what this button does, afterwards it should make sense.

Comment: I agree that "review" is a good choice here, but I'm skeptical of the claim that even many (let alone most) games use "replay" to mean "play the game over".  At the very least, I'd expect "retry" to be far more common, but I honestly can't think of a single example using "replay" in the sense you describe. Maybe it's common in a genre I don't play often?

Comment: @MarkS. it may have been more common back in my arcade days.

Comment: Also, 'review' could mean "Take me to the App Store to post a review", which will ensure the button never gets clicked.

Comment: I am struggling to think of any games that use replay to mean start a new game...

Comment: @Chris: For starting a new game, I do think that "Restart" or "New game" or "Play again" are more common wordings. But, if I were playing a game, and it had just ended, and I saw a button marked "Replay," *as a player* I would naturally assume that clicking that button would let me play again. The relevant conditional probability here is not `P(button is labeled 'Replay', given that it is a restart button)` but rather `P(button is a restart button, given that it is labeled 'Replay')`. The former is quite low; the latter is quite high.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: You may be right. I suspect though that context would be quite important too. Finishing a game of starcraft you probably would be more likely to expect a video replay, finishing a game of flappy birds? You probably expect a start again.

Answer (score 11):

Try **instant replay** for looking back on what has happened in your game and **restart** for replaying the game all over again from the beginning as if the original game had never happened.

Comment: You ignored the *size* of the button! :) It's mentioned! And, there is *no option* for 'restart.' The game is such

Comment: Well then just do "I. Replay" for "Instant Replay" and put in the direction manual what "I. Replay" means, or do "I.R." with an explanation in the manual.

Comment: @Nick I rarely read the manual for games, expecting that the UI of the game will be enough. "I. Replay" looks like bad UI to me.

Comment: I have a game on my phone that uses "Replay" on one screen to watch the last played level, and "Restart" on another screen (after watching) to start the level over. It doesn't seem at all confusing, so I'd recommend sticking with "Replay".

Answer (score 6):

Did you consider adding a "play" icon like this: ▶
as opposed to "replay" icon that would commonly look like this: ↻?

Otherwise, "**Watch replay**" conveys the meaning nicely and takes a little less space than "**Instant replay**".

Comment: Exactly what I thought. I was thinking about the [video icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/video-camera/) though !

Comment: Wonderful suggestion. +1 for the symbolic presentation. However, the other answer is a bit more precise! :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd use a counterclockwise arrow though (turning backwards rather than rolling forwards, which seems more like a "skip" icon to me).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use "**replay**" because of the double meaning of "play:" of a game and of recorded footage.

You can "watch" footage or a game, but both contexts have the same meaning. So, you could use "**rewatch**."

Comment: I don't think "rewatch" is a great choice for a game recap (I'm not saying it's wrong though). I didn't *watch* the game the first time, I played it! I think "rewatch" would be a better choice if the button were in a video player and it replayed the video you had just viewed.

Comment: @ColleenV But the recap system _is_ basically a video player.

Comment: But the game isn't a video, so I'm watching a video of the game I played for the first time, not rewatching a video I've already seen. It's a fine distinction, so I wouldn't say "rewatch" is wrong. I think replay is better because it already has a commonly understood sense of playing back a match or game.

Comment: @ColleenV But also of playing again.

Comment: In AmE, most games I've played use "restart" not "replay", which is probably why I think "rewatch" is a little strange. I've never seen "rewatch" used in this context.

Answer (score 4):

It seem to me that the main priority is to not give the impression that the button will delete the current game. If any player who is not under that impression wants to know what the button does, they will presumably press it and see what happens. I recommend "video" or "recap", but "review" is also good.

Comment: Upvoted for "recap", which seems as good or better than the words "watch", "rewatch", "review" suggested elseanswer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is already a different button with this name, just call the button "Watch".  This conveys the essence of what the button does, allowing the user to watch a game.  As it happens, it is the game just played.